# MVC 4 передача данных из представления в контроллер и сохранение в БД

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, mvc, view

Добрый день! Новичок в MVC, прошу подсказать как правильно сделать следующее.
Есть модель, которая соответствует таблице в БД

```
public class Task
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int ID_initiator { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Укажите дату")]
    [Display(Name = "Дата протокола/поручения")]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd.MM.yyyy}")]
    public DateTime DateProtocolTask { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Номер поручения")]
    public string NumberTask { get; set; }
```

.....

Как передать в модель ID создателя (ID_initiator), если в представлении я выбираю выпадающим списком ФИО инициатора задачи?
Использовать какую-то промежуточную модель? Не могу сообразить.

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался. Использовал DropDownListFor, вместо DropDownList